# Azure SignalR Service Testing

Tags: signalr-hub, azure-signalr

I am trying to run a SignalR hub on a machine on my lan at home using the Azure SignalR Service.
I could not connect to localhost from another machine on my lan so I changed the launch settings to:

```
"applicationUrl": "https://0.0.0.0:5001;http://0.0.0.0:5000"
```

Using this setting I can connect to the HomeController from another machine on my lan:

```
[Route("/")]
public IActionResult Index()
{...
```

When I try to connect to hub I get

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'The SSL connection could not be established, see inner 
exception.'
```

This makes sense as the Azure SignalR service uses TLS.
Do I need to install a certificate on my hosting machine?